How do Christian proponents of the Fine Tuning argument for God justify their probability estimates?
For reference, I am not a Christian but I am interested in hearing theistic perspectives on this.
The fine tuning argument essentially goes that the probability of constants in physics resulting in life is very low given all possible constants. On the other hand, the probability of these constants is high given that a designer existed and wanted to produce life.
But probabilities depend on sample spaces. Who gets to define sample spaces? When we calculate the probability of life producing constants, we implicitly think that the sample space is all possible real numbers. Why?
Secondly, what is the sample space when calculating the designer’s intentions and more importantly the sample space of events when calculating the designer’s existence? Why isn’t there a global sample space that includes all kinds of different universes with different constants but also god? Different answers to these give wildly different probabilities.
The probability of a dice landing on 2 is 1/6. The probability of a unicorn magically making the dice land on 2 if it existed and wanted it to be this way is 1. But what is the probability of this unicorn existing and what would be the corresponding sample space?
It seems as if answers to these questions are arbitrary. If the sample spaces cannot be justified, how is there any justification for any of the probabilities used in the fine tuning argument in the first place?

This has nothing to do with Christianity. It might receive some attention on SE-Philosophy or SE-Physics.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Ignoring that unicorns exist(ed) (hint: real unicorns aren't much like their contemporary depictions), what does it mean to ask about the probability of a unicorn existing? You and I are intelligent designers; what's the probability of either of us existing? What does that mean with respect to the question of whether I wrote this comment or it exists because of a fluke network error or such?

The question would be improved by including some explicit examples of "their probability estimates".


we implicitly think that the sample space is all possible real numbers

Not really. For almost anything, it's not difficult to come up with a number that everyone will agree is far too large to be reasonable.
Suppose most people agree that a value must lie between 700 and 800, while other groups argue for (600–750) and (725–950).
There could be interesting discussions about this, but when it comes to fine tuning, it's almost irrelevant.
With fine tuning, there is a constant: 716.3859…[137-digits]…48±.
It must be accurate to 146 digits or the corresponding physical processes won't work in a way that supports life.
The working "sample space" is that miniscule "±" in the 147th digit.
There's nothing to justify about it.
The "miracle" isn't the probabilities of what comes after the 146th digit, it's that there isn't any choice about the first 146 digits.

What specific constant is this? (Hint: consider mentioning in your Answer!)

@Matthew, it's Finagle's Constant.  (I.e. I just make it up for convenience).

This is going to be a poor answer because I am not a physicist. This probably belongs on Physics.SE, stripped of any appeal to Christians, specifically, as the fine-tuning argument is not inherently Christian.

Who gets to define sample spaces? When we calculate the probability of life producing constants, we implicitly think that the sample space is all possible real numbers. Why?

Not being a physicist, I can't say, though I don't believe "all possible real numbers" is correct either. That said, the argument is of roughly the form "this constant that governs attraction" (to pick an easy-to-understand example) "must be this value within some extremely fine range". But other than "it allows for useful stuff", we don't know of any reason why it shouldn't have half that value, or double, or indeed any positive value at all. In other words, we believe the sample space is large because we can't show any non-teleological reason why it shouldn't be large. This is where physics intersects with philosophy; do we just accept that the constant can only have that value, and that no other universe would exist?

What is the sample space when calculating the designer’s intentions and more importantly the sample space of events when calculating the designer’s existence?

What does this even mean? What, for instance, is the probability that I (the human typing out this Answer) exist? What, given that I do exist, does it mean to ask about that probability? I either do or do not exist. The probability of my existing might, in fact, be infinitesimally low... yet nevertheless I do exist. Intelligent entities do weird things to raw probabilities, in particular because they routinely actualize events which would otherwise be exceedingly implausible.

Existence is binary.  Something either exists (1) or does not exist (2).  Good answer. +1
